# Why do I not need to declare UIAlertViewDelegate in the header?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

I thought I had finally managed to understand the concept of a delegate until the following occurred: I changed my header file to remove the reference to the delegate and the Alert still worked. The only difference is that I lose code hinting.

```
//.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> 
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender;
@end

//.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!" 
                                                      message:@"Message." 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1", @"Button 2", nil];
    [message show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
    }   
}
@end
```

Comment: Yeah... Removing it generates a warning on build.  And if you're losing syntax highlighting, it's because of Xcode.  That is not a language feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in your header is just an indication to the compiler that you intend to implement the delegate methods in your class. You will get warnings if you don't implement delegate methods that are marked as @required, but since most of the delegate methods are usually @optional your code will compile and run fine. That doesn't mean that you shouldn't add the delegates in your header though.

Answer (score 6):

While you have already accepted an answer, there is more to this issue than is addressed there.

`UIAlertViewDelegate` is a **protocol** which implements the **delegate design pattern**.  You may or may not need to officially inform the runtime that you conform to any given protocol (especially if it doesn't have any required methods) by adopting it, but this depends on the design of the class which declares the protocol.  You adopt the protocol in your class by putting the protocol name in <>'s when declaring the class, like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <delegateProtocolName>
```

Since many protocol methods that are delegated are optional methods, they often test to see if the adopting class implements a particular method like this:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegatedMethod:)]) {
    // Do something
}
```

In this case, you do not need to conform to the protocol in your header file because it is testing to see if the specific delegate method has been implemented.

However, the test may be written like this instead (especially if you need to refer to multiple required methods/properties in the same function):

```
if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(delegateProtocolName)]) {
    // Do something
}
```

In this case, you must conform to the protocol in your header file or it will not pass the test.

To quote the documentation for `conformsToProtocol` (taken from [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html) and emphasis added by me):

> **This method determines conformance solely on the basis of the formal
>   declarations in header files**, as illustrated above. It doesn’t check
>   to see whether the methods declared in the protocol are actually
>   implemented—that’s the programmer’s responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is apple doesn't want to require a class to implement the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol. If Apple wished to **require** that, it would make UIAlertView's delegate property of type `id<UIAlertViewDelegate>`. If you look at the documentation, it's not.

[UIAlertView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> `@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate`

They must have their reasons for not making it `@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIAlertViewDelegate> delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

The **<UIAlertViewDelegate>** which you have mentioned in your class means that **you are implementing the AlertView delegate's methods in this class i.e. ViewController** and **delegate:self** means that delegate methods of this object are define in current class.

If you want to define AlertView delegate's method in any other class, then you have to mention <UIAlertViewDelegate> in that class and implement methods in that particular class.

and also you have to change delegate:(classname).