# Why declare in .h when setting a UI object delegate to self?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whenever I create a UI object such as `UITextField` programmatically, I do this:

```
txt.delegate = self;
```

A compiler warning appears and asks me to add `UITextFieldDelegate` in the .h file.

I noticed though that it makes no difference with or without, the code works fine either way.

But the compiler warning disappears. Why is this?

Comment: See this: [Cocoa Core Competencies: Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) and if the code works the same without telling your controller to conform to UITextField's delegate protocol, then you probably are setting the delegate of the text field, but aren't actually utilizing any of its delegate methods.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639886/why-do-i-not-need-to-declare-uialertviewdelegate-in-the-header

Comment: It makes a huge difference. If you declare `txt.delegate = self` and txt is a `UITextField`you are trying to implement the `UITextFields` delegates so methods so things such as `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`. You don't have to implement all its methods just the required mehtods. If you didn't do `txt.delegate = self` (which you don't have to) you won't be able to use any of these methods. You may want to look into http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to set the `delegate` property on your objects unless you are actually using the delegate methods. For example, if you need to know when the `UITextField` is about to begin editing. If you don't need to know when these things occur, you don't need to set the delegate.

Looking at it the other way, if you make your class conform to a delegate method (by adding `<SomeClassDelegate>` in the `.h` file), and then forget to implement required delegate methods, you'll get a warning from the compiler, and a crash when the app runs (and sends a required delegate message to your object).

To answer your question about not adding `UITextFieldDelegate` to your `.h` file, imagine your friend is looking for a French translator. You find a foreign looking man and introduce him. Your friend asks "But can he speak French?" You reply "I don't know". This is your warning.